# Firestore document query allowed with get() but denied using where()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am unit testing the firestore security rules below which allows a member of a group to read the `groups` collection if their userId is a key in the `roles` map.

```
function isMemberOfGroup(userId, groupId) {
    return userId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupId)).data.roles.keys();
}

match /groups/{groupId} {
    allow read: if isMemberOfGroup(request.auth.uid, groupId);
}
```

Sample groups collection

```
{
    name: "Group1"
    roles: {
        uid: "member"
    }
}
```

My unit test performs a `get()` of a single document which succeeds.

It then performs a `get()` using a `where()` query which fails.

```
it("[groups] any member of a group can read", async () => {
    const admin = adminApp({ uid: "admin" });
    const alice = authedApp({ uid: "alice" });

    // Groups collection initialisation
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(
        admin.collection("groups")
        .doc("group1")
        .set({ name: "Group1", roles: { alice: "member" } })
    );

    // This succeeds
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(
        alice.collection("groups")
        .doc("group1")
        .get()
    );

    // This fails
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(
        alice.collection("groups")
            .where(new firebase.firestore.FieldPath('roles', 'alice'), '==', "member")
            .get()
        );
    });
```

It fails with the error:

```
FirebaseError: 
Null value error. for 'list' @ L30
```

where `L30` points to the `allow read` security rule

I know that firestore rules are not responsible for filtering and will deny any request that could contain documents outside of the rule.
However from what I understand, my where() should be limiting this correctly.

Is there a problem with my `where()` query or my rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is still that security rules are not filters.  Since your rule depends on a specific document ID (in your case, `groupId`), that value can never be used in the rule as part of a comparison.  Since rules are not filters, **the rule must work for any possible value of `groupId` without knowing it an advance**, since the rule will not `get()` and check each individual group document.

The security check you have now will simply not work for queries for this reason. Instead, consider storing a list of per-user group access in custom claims or a single document that the user can read, so they can then iterate the list and `get()` only the specific groups they've been told they have access to.

Comment: Trying to figure out how this would work in practice.
If I have a users collection with two documents containing roles e.g.

`user1 {
    name: Alice,
    roles: { group1: "admin", group2: "member" }
}

user2 {
    name: Bob,
    roles: { group1: "member", group3: "admin" }
}`

How would I create a rule to ensure that:
- Alice can read Bob's user document as she is an admin of one of Bob's groups (group1)
- Bob could not read Alice's document as he is not an admin of any of alice's groups

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.

Comment: oops. here it is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962533/firestore-security-rules-for-role-based-access]